# .NET - How to use BackgroundWorker with CMD.executenonquery

Tags: sql, vb.net, multithreading, backgroundworker

In my windows form I have this query that works on around 2,000,000 rows.
Executing the query is freezing the interface and taking about 60 seconds to finish.

Is there a way I can put a progress bar that informs the user that the tasks are being progressed?

I'm new to multi-threading, so any help would be appreciated.

Here's the code that's taking time:

*Breakpoint freezing at cmd.executenonquery()*

```
Public Sub InsertNumberswithMsgID(ByVal messageID As Integer, ByVal tableName As String) 

    Dim cmd As SqlCommand = Nothing

    Try
        cmd = New SqlCommand(("dbo.[InsertNumbers_withMsgID]"), cn)
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@tablename", tableName)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@msgid", messageID)
        cmd.CommandTimeout = 6000
        If Not cn Is Nothing And cn.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then cn.Open()
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

    Catch ex As SqlException

    Catch ex As Exception

    Finally
        If Not cn Is Nothing And cn.State = ConnectionState.Open Then cn.Close()
        If Not cmd Is Nothing Then cmd.Dispose()
    End Try

End Function
```

Comment: I think this link can help you :http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/88605-the-background-worker/ . But instead of using `System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000)` in the BgWorker_DoWork method, you can replace it with the 'code' you supplied above.

Comment: @HelpASisterOut: Did one of the solutions provided help you? If so please let us know (write a comment) - and don't forget to mark the answer. And if not, please tell us what is missing. It helps the community, and the community helps you ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [article](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/88605-the-background-worker/) Arman has mentioned is really a good starting point - use it as a skeleton for your code and place the call of your function where the sleep command is.

But in the example you've provided there is not really a way to update the progress in a progress bar since the stored procedure does everything in one step and returns when it is complete.

Hence, this way you would show 0% before it executes and then 100% after it has finished.

Or you would have to change the stored procedure so it can be called more granularly, i.e. processing 10% of the rows each time, then returning - which would allow you to update the progress bar (which only works if you are allowed to split it into multiple chunks of rows which are to be inserted - if you need to keep it together in one transaction then of course you can't do it).

Alternatively, you can consider using the Marquee style of the progress bar, as described [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/9e51ad57-988e-4c17-98f0-cd2a8abec503/how-to-use-the-stylemarquee-of-progressbar?forum=winforms). In this case you don't need to update the percent values at all.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing you need to do, no matter how you spawn your worker thread, is to disable the parts of the UI that would allow the user to issue the same request again, or else users might click a button multiple times, since all users are impatient.

To spawn your additional thread to do the SQL work in the background, use the BeginExecuteNonQuery function and pass the command object in as the state variable, if you care about returning the number of rows affected.
Show a progress animation or message immediately after that call.

Then, in the callback method for BeginExecuteNonQuery, stop/hide the progress animation/text.

Here's an example:

```
Public Sub InsertNumberswithMsgID(ByVal messageID As Integer, ByVal tableName As String) 

    Dim cmd As SqlCommand = Nothing

    Try
        cmd = New SqlCommand(("dbo.[InsertNumbers_withMsgID]"), cn)
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@tablename", tableName)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@msgid", messageID)
        cmd.CommandTimeout = 6000
        If Not cn Is Nothing And cn.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then cn.Open()
        cmd.BeginExecuteNonQuery(FinishInsertingNumbersWithMsgId, cmd)
        ShowYourProgressAnimation()
    Catch ex As SqlException

    Catch ex As Exception

    Finally
        If Not cn Is Nothing And cn.State = ConnectionState.Open Then cn.Close()
        If Not cmd Is Nothing Then cmd.Dispose()
    End Try

End Sub

Private Sub FinishInsertingNumbersWithMsgId(ByVal ar As IAsyncResult)
    Dim cmd As SqlCommand = ar.AsyncState
    cmd.EndExecuteNonEquery(ar)
    HideYourProgressAnimation()
End Sub
```